# Soccer League Table with objectify

Tags: sql, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, objectify

I would like to make a little backend application for a small soccer league with app engine and I consider to use datastore and objectify instead of a traditional SQL database.

I want to display matchdays and league tables. I also would like to be able to display the league table ranking for ceratin matchdays.

example: 
Lets assume the current matchday is the sixth matchday of the current season. I want to be able to display the league table ranking for the fourth matchdays (its the sum of points of the 1. matchday + 2. matchday + 3. matchday + 4. matchday)

How would I model something like this on app engine using datastore and objectify?
How would a query for a league table look like?

Or is this a good example where I should use traditional SQL database, because with SQL you can do SUM() in your sql statements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You generally have two choices:

- Calculate on the fly (possibly caching)
- Pre-calculate and store

It's hard to say which is better in your case since it depends on data and query volumes. Working on GAE tends to bias developers towards pre-calculation, especially when past data doesn't change. For example, roll up the past data every night. Now your queries are fast.

Comment: "calculating on the fly" seems to be much easier in traditional sql databases. Pre-calculating and storing was also my first approach, but I thought there would be another best practice recommendation. With pre-calculating: for instance I would like to add player statistics for top scorers of the league and top scorers of the team I have to recalculate and store a top scorer entry for the league and to store  top scorer entries for each team and the may need to recalculate in realtime on a matchday. So I guess SQL + memory caching would be better for my league project... What do you think?

Comment: this is not about SQL vs. datastore. it's about pre-calculating vs. calculating on the fly. Both sql & datastore provide you with both options. It's up to you to decide and implement. Considering your app is small don't waste too much time. pick one and go do it. You can always refactor in the future.

Comment: SQL makes a lot of things easy, including things like GROUP BY that do not scale to large data volumes. In your case it probably wouldn't matter since the data volumes are small, but the GAE datastore is a bit single-minded in discouraging any possible activity that won't scale to Google size. There are tradeoffs. If you have tiny data volumes and firmly structured data, there's nothing wrong with an RDBMS.